# How to convert a Django Rest Framework Request object with data to a Django HttpRequest object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django world and I'm trying to build a Django application with 2 function based views wherein one function/view should be able to call the other view. The reason I'm trying to do this is to reduce avoid writing the logic again which is available in my other API.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def PerformActionOne(request):


    result_one = PerformActionTwo(request)
    result_two = DoSomethingElse(result_one)

    return Response(result_two)


@api_view(['POST'])
def PerformActionTwo(request):
    # Performs some calculation and returns rest_framework.response Response with some data in it
    # result is a dictionary 
    result = Calculate() 
    return Response(result)
```

In the above code I'm getting an error in this line `result_one = PerformActionTwo(request)`

> Error:
> Exception Type: AssertionError
> Exception Value:
> The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.

I tried to look it up online and read documentation but I couldn't get a solution to this. I apologize if this is a duplicate question. Any leads on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

not for certain on this but it's possible that the `django.http.HttpRequest` object is on the `rest_framework.request.Request` object under the `_request` param.  Maybe try logging `request._request` to see what type of object it is?

Answer (score 2):

`@api_view` is a decorator that converts your function based view into a class based view (see [Class-based Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/))

The root of what you actually ran into is it adds some wrapper that converts the argument passed into a view from `django.http.HttpRequest` into `rest_framework.request.Request`. This way when you pass the `request` into a function `PerformActionTwo`, the view cannot convert the object properly, as it is not of type `django.http.HttpRequest` anymore.

As far as I understand if your primary goal is to reuse the code, you should extract the body of your `PerformActionTwo` function into a separate function and not decorate it with `@api_view`, this way you can call it from any of your decorated functions.